# repeat value of a row when other row is null

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, missing-data, sql-null

I have a table like this:

```
 id | nu_cns | nu_cpf | co_dim_tempo | sifilis | hiv
908 |   null |    347 |            1 |       y |   n
908 |    708 |   null |            2 |       y |   y
908 |    708 |   null |            3 |       y |   y
```

I need to repeat the fields' values of `nu_cns` and `nu_cpf` when these fields are `null`, for example:

```
 id | nu_cns | nu_cpf | co_dim_tempo | sifilis | hiv
908 |   *708 |    347 |            1 |       y |   n
908 |    708 |   *347 |            2 |       y |   y
908 |    708 |   *347 |            3 |       y |   y
```

Comment: Could you have different sets of values in nu_cns and nu_cpf  for a given id ?

Comment: @PhilCoulson sometimes yes, but, if the result list only one, is ok.

Comment: So if you can have multiple values, how do you decide which value replaces the nulls?

Comment: @PhilCoulson any value can replace the null value. is very rare more than one value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `last_value` with frame clause `rows between unbounded preceding and current row`:

```
select id, first_value(nu_cns) 
  over (partition by id order by nu_cns rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
  from my_table
```

Comment: syntax error at or near "preceeding"
LINE 1: ...ver (order by co_dim_tempo rows between unbounded preceeding...

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo of course it's a typo, should be `preceding`, sorry :>

Comment: Works fine like this: `select id, first_value(nu_cns) over (partition by id order by nu_cns rows between unbounded preceding and current row)` can you edit your answer, please?

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo, sure. Note that it would also work if you changed the ordering with `desc`

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with any value, just do..

```
select *, 
       max(nu_cns) over (partition by id),
       max(nu_cpf) over (partition by id)  
from t;
```